# Error using concatenate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I try to merge text with date in a single cell. I looked online and I found the following options:

```
=G5&TEXT(F5;"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

And

```
=CONCATENATE("ZIMMERMANN U-4600 ";TEXT(F5;"DD/MM/YYYY")).
```

Unfortunatelly , nothing works, although in the other forums everybody was happy with the result. I get a  **#VALUE! - error**.

I played around with the formatting and the languages of windows while giving in the code but nothing helped. 
The code has `;` instead of `,` due to the fact that it is a european office-package (and it doesn't work with  "," either).

Comment: What is in cell F5?

Comment: The date in format DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Are sure that you do not have error in formula names? Eg. in German you should have VERKETTEN instead of concatenate.

Comment: No error there, all other formulas e.g. ADD, COUNT etc. work fine in English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the `#VALUE!` error is coming from the `TEXT(F5;"DD/MM/YYYY")` part. Do trying it alone in a cell as `=TEXT(F5;"DD/MM/YYYY")`. If this also is resulting in `#VALUE!` error, then this is the case.

Unfortunately the pattern `"DD/MM/YYYY"` in `TEXT` function must be according to the locale settings of the Excel and the system the Excel is running on. In German Excel it must be

`=TEXT(F5;"TT/MM/JJJJ")` for example.

Have a look at Control Panel - Region what pattern is used for dates there. Then do using the same in `TEXT` function.

See [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) -> `Other format codes that are available` for another method getting possible format codes directly from the Excel.

This is a big disadvantage of the `TEXT` function if the Excel file shall be exchanged between different users from different locales.

Better approach then would be:

```
=TEXT(DAY(F5);"00")&"/"&TEXT(MONTH(F5);"00")&"/"&TEXT(YEAR(F5);"0000")
```

since the pattern `0` is locale independent.

Comment: That was it, although the formula-command works with English, the Region is set to Greek and instead of "DD/MM/YYYY" it needs "HH/MM/EEEE" to recognize the pattern. Thanks

Comment: @user36510: Yes. This is a big disadvantage of the `TEXT` function if the Excel file shall be exchanged between different users from different locales. See my supplement.